# how to install libX11 on OSx 10.9?

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks, command-line-tool

I am trying to install ROOT (cern.root.ch). When I run ./configure , I get a message that libX11 is missing and must be installed.

I did some research and found that I need to install

1. ) XQuartz (I already have the latest version.)
2. ) Command line tools in Xcode.

I tried installing Command Line Tools from apple's developer website. The installation goes through smoothly but how do I know whether it has been installed? I still get libX11 missing error with root's configure command.

I also tried xcode-select --install and it once went through smoothly and then later again gives error saying this package is no longer maintained - or something of that sort.

I understand I may have multiple installations... But I am still facing the problem of not having libX11 and not being able to install ROOT.

Thanks,
Hershal.

Comment: This question should really be changed to "How to install ROOT on OSx 10.9" or something similar. Otherwise people like me who are interested in the answer to the original question will waste time looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://alexpearce.me/2013/12/root-on-os-x-mavericks/) and the [one referenced](https://alexpearce.me/2012/08/installing-root-on-mountain-lion/) in it suggests you use homebrew ([brew](http://brew.sh/)) to install it

```
$ ruby <(curl -fsS https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)
$ brew doctor
```

Remember to add the Homebrew directory to your PATH by adding the directory (found with brew --prefix) to your .bashrc, .zshrc or whatever shell file you’re using (.bashrc is the OS X default). We’ll also add the XQuartz binaries to the PATH in case anything needs them in the future.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:$PATH
```

Start a new Terminal session to pick up the changes.

Now that Homebrew is installed, we can use it to install the required dependencies. Each may take some time as Homebrew generally compiles from source.

```
$ brew install gfortran # Fortran compiler
$ brew install python   # Python interpreter
$ brew install pcre     # Regular Expressions library
$ brew install fftw     # Fast Fourier Transforms
$ brew install cmake    # Cross-platform make
```

install root

```
$ brew tap homebrew/science
$ brew install --with-cocoa root
```

You don't say whether you have installed [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) as well as the commandline tools but I think you will need it

Comment: Thanks but I want to install root using the conventional method. I already have the latest root 5.34. The link you provided was helpful. It says that they have fixed the issue in later releases of root. And hence my root 5.34 installation went thru smoothly. Now I want 5.30 for some reasons. Don't want to use brew for I like to change paths in .profile to change which version of root is being used. Thanks for the link btw.

Comment: I have installed Xcode and then used xcode-select --install as well installed Command Line Tools using dmg from the apple developer site.